# Which config file to use for each GG example

Tags: gridgain

Which spring-????-config.xml I should use to star GG nodes so the .net example GridClientApiExample works?

Answer (score 1):

Each GridGain example provides a short description of how to run remote nodes in the example documentation.

Usually there are two ways to run remote nodes for the example. The first and, probably, the most convenient one is to run corresponding `*NodeStartup` class from IDE in the examples project. The name of startup class is specified in example documentation. The second way is to start a node with `ggstart.{sh|bat}` script with a configuration file specified in the documentation (if available).

`GridClientApiExample` works only with node started from IDE with `ClientExampleNodeStartup`, and there is a reason for it. The example expects a specific task class (`org.gridgain.examples.misc.client.api.ClientExampleTask`) to be in the node's classpath. Since this is an example-only class, it is not present in node classpath when running `ggstart.{sh|bat}`.

If for some reason you want to run a node with command line script for this example, you should build examples jar file and drop it to `$GRIDGAIN_HOME/libs/ext` (startup script will automatically pick up all additional libraries placed in this folder). Then you can use the same config which `ClientExampleNodeStartup` uses, namely `examples/config/example-compute.xml`

Comment: Many Thanks. It works. For .net users it is not clear path. I do need to start a few GG Nodes manually to see the execution on a grid for several nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ClientExampleNodeStartup` or start node with `ggstart.sh examples/config/example-compute.xml`

Comment: Please also provide some explanation or example of how that would work for the OP to understand. Thank you